# zpl printer tear off issue

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

I am using zpl II script to print 3 x 2 labels. Its a ethernet printer.I am facing problem that after the print label not properly tear off. So the next print not properly printing.Is that any way in zpl script label is tear off properly adjest.

Answer (score 1):

What is exactly your problem?

I can give you example of my zpl code:

```
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR5,5~SD15^LRN^CI0^MMT^PW295^LL0236^LS0^FT29,177^A0N,17,19^FH\^FD_text_^FS^XZ
```

If I want to tear off: I set MMT. If I want to cut, I'm changing this parameter to MMC.

Comment: It may not have helped the OP, but it helped point me at the MMT/MMC toggle. Thanks!

Comment: I'm very happy that I could help :)